# Rstudio takes long time to start

Tags: r, rstudio

Since my Rstudio has changed the directory address from "C:/Documents" to "C:/datascientist"and has updated to the latest version. It takes a long time to start my Rstudio. Some ideas about to check the problems or fix the problems would be appreciated. Thank you.

And it shows up the following message when I open up the Rstudio

> "The Rstudio server is taking a long time to respond. It is possible that your R session has become unresponsive. Do you want to terminate the currently running R session?"
>   [image]

Comment: C:data scientist isn't a valid path

Comment: sorry it's C:/data scientist

Comment: There have been problems in the past where R and/or RStudio does not work well *at all* with a space anywhere in the working directory path. It feels non-optimal, certainly, but try running RStudio with a working path without spaces.

Comment: As recommended, I change my directory path to "C:/datascientist". Speed is improved obviously, but still takes about 45 seconds to start. What should I do to further improve the response time?

Comment: Do you have a workspace saved in that directory? When it comes up, does it already have data loaded in the environment?

Comment: Yes. So I have to delete the data or workspace already loaded in the environment if I want to improve the speed?

Answer (score 3):

I also had this unresponsive message when I went into Rstudio. Which is how I found this post (now 9 months old) and I tried reinstalling etc. as suggested above without success.

I found that if I cleared my global environment in R using

```
rm(list=ls())
```

(as suggested by Jonathan McPherson in an R blog post about clearing the global environment) and then opened R studio as an administrator it has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The way easy for your problem is to go work directory from navigator from your pc, then you will go to directory and then erease .Rdata that are in your folder. 
And, no more.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, I wasted a couple of hours fixing the issue. After trying to uninstalling/reinstalling R/RStudio many times, cleaning the cache, .R startup files, etc., what it worked for me is:

1. Start R (not RStudio).
2. Clean the environment with: `rm(list=ls())`
3. Close R and save the environment (click "yes" when the prompt appears)
4. Open RStudio, it should work

In my case I was running a heavy-memory Bayesian model which I knew was causing problems as it was being saved in the environment and crushing R/Rstudio. Hope this helps someone else out there. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me any time. I hope it works for you or anyone with the same issue. this issue for me occured while working with getwd() setwd() and while i used save() load() functions.

1. I uninstalled my Rstudio (it is not enough)
2. then i removed all the rstudio related files in appdata/local and rstudio working directory(history and files)
3. reinstalled Rstudio and it resolved fortunately

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on Windows 10 and tried to fix it by un- and re-installing R and RStudio - which did not work.

What did it for me was to clear my local DNS cache. This is how you do it on Windows:

1. type "run" in the windows (taskbar) search
2. In the windows that pops up type: "ipconfig /flushdns" and press enter